# MacOS: how to get "Last opened" attribute of file?

Tags: swift, macos, file

In some files in OS exist "Last opened" attribute:

[image]

modified and opened attribute is possible to get by the following way:

```
//modified date
try? FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: url.path)[FileAttributeKey.modificationDate] as? Date

//creation date
try? FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: url.path)[FileAttributeKey.creationDate] as? Date
```

But how to get "Last opened" date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no way to get the last time the file was *opened*.  Instead, you have to get the last time it was last *read*, *written* or its directory entry was modified.

Leo's suggestion in comments for another answer to use `URLResourceValues.contentAccessDate` is probably the cleanest way, especially since you already have a URL, which is typically the case these days.

```
func lastAccessDate(forURL url: URL) -> Date?
{
    return try? url.resourceValues(
        forKeys: [.contentAccessDateKey]).contentAccessDate
}
```

You can also reach down into the BSD layer using the path:

```
import Darwin // or Foundation

func lastAccessDate(forFileAtPath path: String) -> Date?
{
    return path.withCString
    {
        var statStruct = Darwin.stat()
        guard  stat($0, &statStruct) == 0 else { return nil }
        return Date(
            timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(statStruct.st_atimespec.tv_sec)
        )
    }
}
```

I'm not 100% of the of the behavior of `resourceValues` if the URL specified is a symbolic link, but `stat()` will return information about the file system inode pointed to by the link.  If you want information directly about the link itself, use `lstat()` instead. `stat()` and `lstat()` are the same otherwise.

I'm pretty sure that `URLResourceValues.contentAccessDate` uses either `stat()` or `lstat()` under the hood.

One thing to keep in mind is that the last access time is *not* the last time the file was opened, but rather the last time it was *read*.  The the `man` page for `stat` says:

> The time-related fields of struct stat are as follows:
>
> st_atime         Time when file data last accessed.  Changed by the mknod(2), utimes(2) and read(2) system calls.
>
> st_mtime         Time when file data last modified.  Changed by the mknod(2), utimes(2) and write(2) system calls.
>
> st_ctime         Time when file status was last changed (inode data modification).  Changed by the chmod(2), chown(2), link(2), mknod(2), rename(2), unlink(2),
> utimes(2) and write(2) system calls.
>
> st_birthtime     Time of file creation. Only set once when the file is created. This field is only available in the 64 bit inode variants. On filesystems where
> birthtime is not available, this field is set to 0 (i.e. epoch).

There the `man` page is referring to the 32-bit member field names, but the same would apply to the 64-bit names, `st_atimespec`, `st_mtimespec`, `st_ctimespec`, and `st_birthtimespec`.

To appromixate the getting the last time a file was opened, you'd want to get the the latest of `st_atimespec`, `st_mtimespec` and maybe `st_ctimespec` if you also want to include include changes to the directory entry that don't modify the contents, such as renaming the file or setting its permissions.  So you'd need something like this:

```swift
func lastReadOrWrite(forFileAtPath path: String) -> Date?
{
    return path.withCString
    {
        var statStruct = Darwin.stat()
        guard  stat($0, &statStruct) == 0 else { return nil }
        let lastRead = Date(
            timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(statStruct.st_atimespec.tv_sec)
        )
        let lastWrite = Date(
            timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(statStruct.st_mtimespec.tv_sec)
        )

        // If you want to include dir entry updates
        let lastDirEntryChange = Date(
            timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(statStruct.st_ctimespec.tv_sec)
        )

        return max( lastRead, max(lastWrite, lastDirEntryChange) )
    }
}
```

or using `URLResourceValues`

```swift
func lastReadOrWriteDate(forURL url: URL) -> Date?
{
    let valKeys: Set<URLResourceKey> =
        [.contentAccessDateKey, .contentModificationDateKey, .attributeModificationDateKey]

    guard let urlVals = try? url.resourceValues(forKeys:valKeys)
    else { return nil }

    let lastRead      = urlVals.contentAccessDate         ?? .distantPast
    let lastWrite     = urlVals.contentModificationDate   ?? .distantPast

    // If you want to include dir entry updates
    let lastAttribMod = urlVals.attributeModificationDate ?? .distantPast

    return max(lastRead, max(lastWrite, lastAttribMod))
}
```

Of course, if some process simply opens a file and then closes it without reading or writing, that will go unnoticed, but then if it didn't read or write, does it matter that it opened the file?

Comment: Doublechecked - last access and last open is not the same dates.... Example: if you open "Applications" folder and will sort it by last open date - it will sort not by the same way as in case of your code sorted by "lastAccessDate"

Comment: @Andrew___Pls_Support_UA, I updated my answer.  Both methods I showed actually get the last time the file was *read*, but doesn't include when it was *written*.   Also keep in mind that if you're comparing with Finder results for the `Applications` folder, that Finder does some magic where it merges `/Applications` and `/System/Applications` in its UI.  You won't get the same results in your app, unless you do a similar merge.